# Can we determine whether $\frac i{2\sqrt s}$ (where $s$ is the transform variable of Laplace transform and $i=\sqrt{-1}$) is positive or not?

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

I have just started Integral transformations and right now I know very basic things about Laplace and Fourier transformations. While surfing through YouTube, I came across a video:

**Find the Laplace transformation of $\frac{\cos\sqrt t}{\sqrt t},t>0.$**

But I'm not aware of the properties that he (the YT guy) used to evaluate it, yet. The problem seemed interesting to me so I decided to give it a try (using the definition of Laplace transformation).

**My work so far:**

We have:

$$\mathcal L\left\{\frac{\cos\sqrt t}{\sqrt t}\right\}=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st}\cdot\frac{\cos\sqrt t}{\sqrt t}\,dt\\\\=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\cdot\frac{e^{i\sqrt t}+e^{-i\sqrt t}}{2\sqrt t}\,dt\\\\=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-su^2}(e^{iu}+e^{-iu})\,du,\text{ via the substitution }\sqrt t=u\\\\=\int_0^{\infty}\left(e^{-s(u^2-iu/s)}+e^{-s(u^2+iu/s)}\right)\,du\\\\=e^{\frac{-1}{4s}}\int_0^{\infty}\left[\exp\left(-s\left(u-\frac i{2s}\right)^2\right)+\exp\left(-s\left(u+\frac i{2s}\right)^2\right)\right]\,du,\text{ via completing the squares}\\\\=\frac{e^{\frac{-1}{4s}}}{\sqrt s}\left[\int_{-\frac i{2\sqrt s}}^{\infty}e^{-v^2}\,dv+\int_{\frac i{2\sqrt s}}^{\infty}e^{-w^2}\,dw\right],\text{ via the substitutions }v=\sqrt s\left(u-\frac i{2s}\right)\text{ and }w=\sqrt s\left(u+\frac i{2s}\right).$$ I got stuck here due to the lower limits of the integrals above.

The answer to this question is: $\sqrt{\fracπs}\cdot e^{-\frac1{4s}}$.

As far as I know we cannot determine whether $\frac i{2\sqrt s}$ is positive or not. But if I consider: $\frac i{2\sqrt s}>0.$ Then we can easily see that the required Laplace transform is given by:$$\frac{e^{-\frac1{4s}}}{\sqrt s}\left[\int_0^{\infty}e^{-v^2}\,dv+\int_0^{\infty}e^{-w^2}\, dw\right].$$ Both the above integrals are equal and can be evaluated by substituting either $v^2=x$ or $w^2=x.$ Then we have:
\begin{align}
\mathcal L\left\{\frac{\cos\sqrt t}{\sqrt t}\right\}&=\frac{e^{-\frac1{4s}}}{\sqrt s}\cdot2\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}2\\\\&=\frac{e^{-\frac1{4s}}}{\sqrt s}\cdot\sqrtπ\\\\&=\sqrt{\fracπs}\cdot e^{-\frac1{4s}}.
\end{align}
Which matches with the answer.

Please suggest, how to tackle the lower bounds or how to modify my method?

(Sorry for the tittle. Couldn't think of a proper one..)

Comment: Complex numbers cannot be positive, negative or greater or lower than other complex number. There cannot be linear order on $\;\Bbb C\;$ the way there exists in $\;\Bbb R\;$ .

Comment: The trick is to do the $u$ substitution before switching to complex exponentials. Then since the integrand is even, the integral can be extended to $-\infty$ to $\infty$ which gets rid of your ambiguity with the bounds.

Comment: @Ninad, yes sir... Got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @DonAntonio, yes sir I know that though according to *Well Ordering Principle, * every set can be well ordered. But this result is equivalent to axiom of choice and we cannot make $\mathbb C$ an ordered set as we generally do with $\mathbb R.$ But was confused whether it is possible to consider $\frac i{2\sqrt s}>0$ or not here.. Got my answer, **NO.** But this reminds me of the following property: $\mathcal L\{e^{at}\}=\frac1{s-a},$ where $\boxed{s>a.}$ We know $s\in\mathbb C$ and $\Re(s)>0.$ So how's this possible here, sir? Please explain..

Comment: (continued) The integral:$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\cdot e^{at}\, dt=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(s-a)t}\, dt$$ converges for $s>a.$ But $s\in\mathbb C. $ How to justify this, sir???

Comment: @DhrubajyotiBhattacharjee:  yes, any set can be well ordered (if you believe AC), but that is not important here.  The important thing about the order on $\Bbb R$ (which is not a well order, but is a total order) is that it respects the arithmetic operations, so $a \lt b \implies a+c \lt b+c$ for example.  There is no order on $C$ that does that.  The easiest way to see it is to ask whether $i \gt 0$.  If it is, you should have $i^2=-1 \gt 0$.  If not, $-i \gt 0$ and you should have $(-i)^2 \gt 0$

Comment: @Ross Millikan, got it sir. Thank you. Sir will you please explain: $\mathcal L\{e^{at}\}=\frac1{s-a}, s>a.$ Although $s\in\mathbb C$.

Comment: I believe it converges for $Re(s) \gt Re(a)$.  That is well defined, even in the complex numbers because the comparison is done in the reals.  I never took Laplace transforms, so you should check in your book, but I think you assume $s$ has a large enough real part to make things converge when you need it.

Comment: Currently I'm reading *Integral Transforms and their applications* by Lokenath Debnath and Dambaru Bhatta. In this book, it is only mentioned that $s>a.$ I have also checked an engineering mathematics book, there is also written the same thing. But in the introduction to Laplace Transform section , they did mention that $s$ is **real** (i.e., $\Im(s)=0$) or complex number. So it is possible that by $s>a$ we actually mean $\Re(s)>\Re(a).$ Thank you sir for responding..

Comment: I will try to look for some other books regarding this matter. But if I cannot find any satisfying answer to this.. I'll explicitly post it as a question or query here..

Comment: If we make the change of variables $z = a x + b$ in $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) dx$, we get an integral along an infinite line $\gamma$ in the complex plane. If $\operatorname {Re} s > 0$ (otherwise $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) dx$ diverges), $\gamma$ can be deformed to coincide with the real line without changing the value of the integral. The choice of a branch of the square root in $\sqrt s$ determines whether $\gamma$ can be deformed into $(-\infty, \infty)$ or into $(\infty, -\infty)$.

Comment: First of all, thank you sir for letting me know. I have some doubts. Sorry if you found this lame but I haven't studied complex analysis yet so couldn't really make out the last line of your comment. BTW what did you want to mean by $(\infty, -\infty)$ ? I know what does $(\infty, -\infty)$ mean but am seeing the later one for the first time. And recently I have seen the derivation of Laplace transform from Fourier transform, which is basically a generalization, so got to learn there that by $s>0$ they really want to mean that $\Re(s)>0.$